# How do I access Advanced permissions menu for folders in SharePoint Online when link is missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I need to grant unique permissions for a folder from SharePoint Online. About one week ago, I was able to access the Advanced permissions by

1. Selecting the folder
2. Clicking i to open details pane
3. Clicking on Manage access link
4. Clicking on the Advanced link

Now, the Advanced link is no longer visible. Looks like the look and feel for the Manage Access menu has changed as well.

Do you know of how we are supposed to manage advanced permissions for items now that the link to Advanced is gone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it has been changed. You can use "Manage Access" panel to manage permissions for the selected item. The new document library and list experience in SharePoint Online is faster and is easier to use.

If you want to navigate to the classic Manage Permissions page, you need to return to the classic SharePoint by clicking “**Return to classic SharePoint**” in the bottom, left corner of the page to switch to classic experiences. And then select the folder/item -> Under Files tab on the ribbon, click on "Share With" -> Advanced.

[image]

Comment: Switching to classic SharePoint to access the Advanced menu worked as a workaround for me. Thanks. 

According to Microsoft, it's a bug and they are looking into fixing it. It was not intentional to remove the link to Advanced from the modern SharePoint. The manage access menu cannot do all the things that the Advanced menu can.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Link-to-Advanced-permissions-management-disappeared-from/m-p/294349#M24179